# Want to check text box value for duplicates in column before I add to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

im using vbs in excel 2010 and i have a form that adds data to this spreadsheet...that's all fine but i need to be able to check if im not duplicating data.

there is one column in spreadsheet where all numbers should be unique.

I'd like to check the text box value in the form against the column entries before i add the value .

this is all i need and this mini project of mine is done

this is the current coding i have that adds the data to sheet

```
Private Sub cmdbtnSave_Click()
Dim vNewRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = DataTable
    ' Find the next empty row
    vNewRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ' Check for data in Field 1
    If Trim(Me.invoicemonth.Value) = "" Then
        Me.invoicemonth.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter invoice month!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Check for data in Field 2
    If Trim(Me.dfrdate.Value) = "" Then
        Me.dfrdate.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter DFR date!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Check for data in Field 3
    If Trim(Me.actype.Value) = "" Then
        Me.actype.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter Airfraft Type!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' check a/c rego
    If Trim(Me.acrego.Value) = "" Then
        Me.acrego.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter Aircraft Rego!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' check client
    If Trim(Me.client.Value) = "" Then
        Me.client.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter Client"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' check destination
    If Trim(Me.dest.Value) = "" Then
        Me.dest.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter in destination"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' check dfr hours
    If Trim(Me.dfrhrs.Value) = "" Then
        Me.dfrhrs.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter DFR Hours"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' check if pilots name is entered
    If Trim(Me.Pilots.Value) = "" Then
        Me.Pilots.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please input pilot name ya! wwsshhh!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'check if tech log hrs is entered
    If Trim(Me.txt_tloghrs.Value) = "" Then
        Me.txt_tloghrs.SetFocus
        MsgBox "wwsshh!! putim tech log hrs ya!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'check if tech log number is in
     If Trim(Me.txt_tlogno.Value) = "" Then
        Me.txt_tlogno.SetFocus
        MsgBox "wwsshh!! mi needim numbba blo displa tech log ya!"
        Exit Sub
     End If

    'check if engineer's name is entered
     If Trim(Me.cmb_eng.Value) = "" Then
        Me.cmb_eng.SetFocus
        MsgBox "WWSSHH! NA NEM BLO ENGINEER EM HUSAIT?"
        Exit Sub
     End If

    'check if fuel supplier is put in
     If Trim(Me.cmb_fsupply.Value) = "" Then
        Me.cmb_fsupply.SetFocus
        MsgBox "if no input select/type NULL"
        Exit Sub
     End If

    'check if branch
     If Trim(Me.cmb_branch.Value) = "" Then
        Me.cmb_branch.SetFocus
        MsgBox "if no input select/type NULL"
        Exit Sub
     End If

    'check if tech log number is in
     If Trim(Me.txt_finvoice.Value) = "" Then
        Me.txt_finvoice.SetFocus
        MsgBox "if no input select/type NULL"
        Exit Sub
     End If

    'check fuel liters
    If Trim(Me.txt_ltrs.Value) = "" Then
        Me.txt_ltrs.SetFocus
        MsgBox "if no input select/type NULL"
        Exit Sub
     End If


    ' Input the data in the Data Table
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 1).Value = Me.invoicemonth.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 2).Value = Me.dfrdate.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 3).Value = Me.dfrnumber.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 4).Value = Me.actype.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 5).Value = Me.acrego.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 6).Value = Me.client.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 7).Value = Me.dest.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 8).Value = Me.dfrhrs.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 9).Value = Me.Pilots.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 10).Value = Me.txt_tloghrs.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 11).Value = Me.txt_tlogno.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 12).Value = Me.cmb_eng.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 13).Value = Me.cmb_fsupply.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 14).Value = Me.cmb_branch.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 15).Value = Me.txt_finvoice.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 16).Value = Me.cmb_whosupply.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 17).Value = Me.txt_ltrs.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 1).Activate

    ' Clear all fields and reset the form
    Me.invoicemonth.Value = ""
    Me.dfrdate.Value = ""
    Me.dfrnumber.Value = ""
    Me.actype.Value = ""
    Me.acrego.Value = ""
    Me.client.Value = ""
    Me.dest.Value = ""
    Me.dfrhrs.Value = ""
    Me.Pilots.Value = ""
    Me.txt_tloghrs.Value = ""
    Me.txt_tlogno.Value = ""
    Me.cmb_eng.Value = ""
    Me.cmb_fsupply.Value = ""
    Me.cmb_branch.Value = ""
    Me.txt_finvoice.Value = ""
    Me.cmb_whosupply.Value = ""
    Me.txt_ltrs.Value = ""
    Me.invoicemonth.SetFocus`
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, consider creating separate subroutines for Clear, and Save, as well as Validate.  That way you can adapt your code to more purposes.  Also, you don't need to put "Me." in every line.

Comment: @AbhishekAsthana, I believe the OP was asking how to check against duplicates, and the code represented only checks against empty values, saves the data and clears the form.

Answer (score 0):

Using subroutines, you can perform this more easily than in one big chunk.  You would need to set your values for certain variables like "ws" upon UserForm activation.

Your Save Button click event would be just a few lines then, executing each subroutine.  First checking for Duplicates, then Checking for Empties, then Copying the Data, Saving the Workbook, and Clearing the Form for another entry.  You will still have to use whatever you are doing to navigate the records or take into account which row on which to put the data.  I believe in the example you used "VNewRow".

```
Private Sub cmdbtnSave_Click()

    If IsDuplicate() = False Then   
        Call CheckEmpty
        Call SaveData
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Call ClearData
    Else
        MsgBox("Duplicate records exist for " & txtBoxToCheck.Value & "!")
        'Anything else you want to accomplish, such as reset the form
        'You can Call ClearData here.  
    End If

End Sub
```

Then you would need a subroutine to check for Duplicates on the column that needs to be all unique. In this example, "txtBoxToCheck" is the name of the textbox and it is located on Sheet1 Column "A".  When this runs it will return False if there are no duplicates, and True if there are.  Then the save event will either save or not based on that.

```
Function IsDuplicate() As Boolean
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim resultCheck As Boolean
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   'gets last row of Sheet1

For row = 2 to lastRow     'Assuming you have a Header Row and Data begins on row 2.
    If txtBoxToCheck.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row , 1).Value Then
        resultCheck = True
        End For
    Else
        resultCheck = False
    End If
Next row      'loop until last row of sheet1
IsDuplicate = resultCheck
End Sub
```

This would lose your custom message boxes but would save you time.  In this example, if you set the Tag property on each control that can't be empty. In the example, they are tagged with "NoEmpty".  You could remove your list of If/Then Statements with each having the same code and only one value changes and call this instead.

```
Private Sub CheckEmpty()

    Dim ctl As MSForms.Control

    For Each ctl In YourForm.Controls   'Set to your form name
        If ctl.Tag = "NoEmpty" Then
            If (ctl.Value = "")) Then
                MsgBox ("Set value for " & ctl.Name)
                ctl.SetFocus      
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

That would relieve you of an if statement for each cell checking for blank.

You would have a separate subroutine for SaveData.  Taking from your original code, without the "Me."

```
Private Sub SaveData()
    'Input the data in the Data Table
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 1).Value = invoicemonth.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 2).Value = dfrdate.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 3).Value = dfrnumber.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 4).Value = actype.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 5).Value = acrego.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 6).Value = client.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 7).Value = dest.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 8).Value = dfrhrs.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 9).Value = Pilots.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 10).Value = txt_tloghrs.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 11).Value = txt_tlogno.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 12).Value = cmb_eng.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 13).Value = cmb_fsupply.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 14).Value = cmb_branch.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 15).Value = txt_finvoice.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 16).Value = cmb_whosupply.Value
    ws.Cells(vNewRow, 17).Value = txt_ltrs.Value

End Sub
```

And another for ClearData, again using your code from above without the "Me."

```
Private Sub ClearData()
    'Clear all fields and reset the form
    invoicemonth.Value = ""
    dfrdate.Value = ""
    dfrnumber.Value = ""
    actype.Value = ""
    acrego.Value = ""
    client.Value = ""
    dest.Value = ""
    dfrhrs.Value = ""
    Pilots.Value = ""
    txt_tloghrs.Value = ""
    txt_tlogno.Value = ""
    cmb_eng.Value = ""
    cmb_fsupply.Value = ""
    cmb_branch.Value = ""
    txt_finvoice.Value = ""
    cmb_whosupply.Value = ""
    txt_ltrs.Value = ""
    invoicemonth.SetFocus

 End Sub
```

In Summary, by doing it this way, you can more easily adapt your code for future projects that are similar, while making it easier for debugging later by you or other people who might have to work on your code. Keep the navigation and other validation methods in place and just modify where the data comes from and goes, and the specific names of the UserForm Controls, worksheets, etc.

edit: added clarification and more comments to code.